# PHP code can insert image to excel file and open it correctly in MS Excel?

Tags: php, image, phpexcel

I already have a document of excel and I want to use php to insert an image to that excel.

Is it possible to do that? How to implement it (code)?

Thanks,

Comment: I think it is easy to do if the image is hosted somewhere, you just need to change the headers. If the image is embedded look at phpexcel

Comment: I just want to know it's possible or not. and now it's possible so what is a simple code to do that just like $excel->insertImage(...) or what. Thanks for help

Comment: It's perfectly possible, but please provide a few details of what Excel reading/writing libraries you are using?

Answer (score 6):

```
$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$fileName = 'test.xlsx';

// Load the workbook
$objPHPExcelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcelReader->load($fileName);

// Add an image to the worksheet
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('My Image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('The Image that I am inserting');
$objDrawing->setPath('./images/myImage.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B2');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

// Save the workbook
$objPHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,$fileType);
$objPHPExcelWriter->save($fileName);
```