# How do I export data and a base64 image to excel using PHP?

Tags: php, excel, export, base64

I'm trying to export the following to excel but the image is not coming through.

Example:

```
$today = date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time());
header ("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"export.xls\"" );
echo '
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Client ID</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Client Name</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">No. of Staff</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">No. of Events</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Fail all\'s</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Fail Section</th>
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Fail all %</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap="nowrap">8</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap">SEAI</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><div> 17 </div></td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><div> 354 </div></td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><div> 7 </div></td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><div> 0 </div></td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap"><div> 1.98% </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
';
```

I have tried the following with out success:

```
echo file_get_contents(base64_decode($img));
```

With and without the  tag and with and without the file_get_contents and base64_decode.

I feel that is should be possible but I'm missing something :(. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is it an actual image? When I tried to output the decoded value it gave me `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`

Comment: It's an image all right, I've edited the question so that the Fail all's are escaped.

Comment: But how do I get the image into Excel?

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood the logics. I have added an answer, you might want to refer to.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Now, I need the same thing but I can't find any question closer to this.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, you are trying to create an excel file (XLS) keeping headers.

Headers are not enough!

You need set of libraries. I would recommend you to do use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)
You can add images easily to it. Keep this library handy! It can do many more stuff.

Once you have installed it, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337142/php-code-can-insert-image-to-excel-file-and-open-it-correctly-in-ms-excel) for more step by step instructions.

Comment: Does this embed the image or does it just create a link to it?

Comment: it compiles the image. I.e. if that image is on ur machine, u need to define path from the root of OS not just document... just as fpdf (for pdf), I am not sure if it does but, give a try! :) I googled because I know as much as u know but, I had some spare time! :)

Comment: It embeds the image, so that it's actually contained in the  generated .xls file (just like Excel itself does). It does this by creating a real Excel file (just like Excel does)

Answer (score 0):

Try complete solution using PHPExcel that I also recommend for this job.

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/271473

Comment: Does this embed the image or does it just create a link to it?

Comment: Excel files store images internally, not as links.... and PHPExcel is a library for creating real Excel files, not html markup with a .xls extension