# Insert Image in csv file using php script

Tags: php, excel, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code can insert image to excel file and open it correctly in MS Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337142/php-code-can-insert-image-to-excel-file-and-open-it-correctly-in-ms-excel)

I want to add images in `.csv` file with the help of PHP script. I also don't know if it is possible or not.

[image]

Comment: why adding image store image in a physical location and store path in csv or excel file and call whenever it is needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not possible straight away. By the specs, [CSV files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) are text-based, they do not have anything like images or other type of binary data.

So unless both the generator and the reader agree on a format, such as a [Data-URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), there is no way to include graphic data.

You might want to create a different kind of file, like a spreadsheet (.odt, .xls/.xlsx), however those are not CSV files you ask for.

Comment: ok. So is this possible in excel file??
can I add images in excel file using php script???

Comment: @parag bhargav: As far as I know, the Excel file-type has support for binary- and image-data. If you have Excel installed, any PHP script can create and edit these files via the COM interface of MS Office. Also search around for alternative solutions.

Comment: If I insert images in excel file as you told me that it is possible after that I save as that excel file into .csv file. so, is this possible that image remain same and also seen in .csv file???

Comment: No, CSV file has no images. It is only text.

Comment: One last question for insert images in excel file i need to include some PHPExcel class file?? I heard that whenever we need to do any operation in excel file using PHP we need to include this class file.

Comment: Not that one specifically, but in general a library is used for that, yes. If you found many examples wth Phpexcel, you might want to start with that one.

Comment: Thanks Men. You save my Time.
I tried to import images in excel file and its work fine. Image inserted successfully. I write the code with help of PHPExcel class.
Thanks Again.