# How to upload image from my pc when upload record using csv file

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have bunch upload in my admin panel using csv.so how to upload image when I am inserting record using csv.using php for uploading record.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to insert an image inside csv or how is it can you explain more

Comment: i am uploading record using csv file. now a case where there are image has  to be uploaded for record. so how can i add image in csv file for uploading?

Comment: you can add a link to the actual image inside cvs. And upload image into a seperate directory where you want it to be, pointing image path to the CVS.

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: @doriyamaulik study through this link. Please do some r & d before putting a topic in SO. It will help you a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061660/insert-image-in-csv-file-using-php-script

Answer (score 0):

1. Before inserting a record into CSV upload image to the directory of your choice, for example: /img/myimage123.jpg
2. In CSV file, add location of this new image uploaded as a string '/img/myimage123.jpg'

In this way you can safely path image information into CSV.

If you need to save image file itself inside CSV, then I would suggest using file_get_contents('image_file.jpg'), and saving in escaped inside CSV, but my above method is preferred to this  one.