# Inserting image into an excel sheet using Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, excel

I am trying to programmatically insert images into a cell of an Excel sheet. All the images are located on my local machine. I was using msexcel-builder module but it doesn't seem to have the capability to insert image files into a cell.

After Googling around, I saw this post: [PHP code can insert image to excel file and open it correctly in MS Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337142/php-code-can-insert-image-to-excel-file-and-open-it-correctly-in-ms-excel) but it's using PHP and I'd rather avoid it if I could.

Are there any NPM modules out there that will allow me to do this?

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 6):

These are a few npm modules that support inserting images into an excel spreadsheet:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxl
https://www.npmjs.com/package/excellent
https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node

Comment: I'll add this too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

Comment: @Antenaina, it asked insertion of the image inside excel cell, not on the top of cells. [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) can't insert picture inside the cell, but it can insert the image, that will be on the top of a few cells.

Comment: @Rizwan Thanks for the remark.