# PHP/Javascript generate and autodownload excel file

Tags: javascript, php, excel, wordpress

Hi so there are many topics about this, yet they are all 4-5 years old using PHPExcel that was not updated for 2 years now and it's status is "Failing". I am need this as a part of wordpress plugin.
There is also possibility to use just javascript but I had no luck there either. I found some that are able to create xls files, but they did not supported inserting of an image.

What I need to do:

- can be any format that is openable via Excel and looks like excel
- put image into excel-like file (this has to be included in the file)
- get data from database and put them in there
- Data that needs to be inserted into document may vary so they are not entirely representable as one table

This all happens when user pushes some button and it downloads. Now I know how to create button to trigger AJAX that do this action and gets my data, but I have no idea what library is currently usable for this.

UPDATE:
so I tried out PHPExcel, this code but with no luck
so, I added small action to try out PHPExcel but I had no luck... Downloaded file is corrupted, I almost have a feeling the file is actually not containing any data from $objPHPExcel

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['download'] ) ) {
            require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'hello world!');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Chesse1');
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="helloworld.xlsx"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
});
```

Comment: PHPExcel is still being developed. The build "failing" status you see is because of their code-style not meeting their defined standards. You should be fine with your 4-5 year old SO posts and using PHPExcel as it still seems to be the best option for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11343459/2232127

Comment: Oh ok thanks! I thought that it means that it is not recommended to be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

OK so PHPExcel even though it's status is failing is still working just fine and all 2-4 year old posts on stackoverflow are still valid.